# Navigation Menu item click not working

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, onclicklistener

I have created a side-menu(Navigation Menu) for my app and have overridden the OnOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) method in order to add some custom behavior when each menu item is clicked. However, after writing some code so that when the first menu item is clicked(nav_home <- id) a Toast will be displayed,nothing happens when i click on it and i cannot figure out the problem here...

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // When a menu item is clicked, then depending on it's id start a new Activity
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here's my whole MainActivity class :

```
package com.dcv.spdesigns.dokkancards;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.dcv.spdesigns.dokkancards.model.ImageAdapter;
import com.dcv.spdesigns.dokkancards.ui.CardViewActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
GridView gridView;

// NavMenu member vars
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle; // Button for toggling the side menu

private Toolbar mToolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Get Screen Size Details
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    final int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridViewLayout);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this)); // used to set the contents of the GridView-in this case images-

    // When an item from the GridView gets clicked
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // Create a new Intent...
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CardViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Card Index",position);
            intent.putExtra("SCREEN_WIDTH",width);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.navActionBar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar); // check quick doq
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    mToolbar.setTitle("");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_closed); // Instantiating our button

    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();


}

// When an item from the Action Bar gets tapped, then...
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // When a menu item is clicked, then depending on it's id start a new Activity
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Main xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context="com.dcv.spdesigns.dokkancards.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Include the custom Action Bar we created -->

    <include layout="@layout/navigation_action_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/gridViewLayout"/>

    <!-- Add text & images -->
</LinearLayout>

<!-- The actual side menu Nav View -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: comment the condition : if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {

Comment: i've tried that but it did not work

Comment: `a Toast will be displayed,nothing happens` , there is nothing else , what are you expecting

Comment: i expect nothing more...but like i said that does not work. no Toasts get displayed

Comment: post the complete code

Comment: you need to initialize nav-view and use `setNavigationItemSelectedListener`

Comment: add the menu code please

Comment: just added it ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hard to tell without the complete code, but a common source for this problem is that the navigation is not on top of all other elements. In order to ensure this, place the the header/navigation references in your layout to the complete bottom. The lower an item is in your layout xml, the higher its z-index.

The final lines of your layout should look something like this:

```
    ...
    <include layout="@layout/header" />
    <include layout="@layout/navigation" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Additionally, I don't see you closing your DrawerLayout tag.

The way I detect clicks in the navigation is generally somewhat different as well. I implement the header and navigation something like this::

```
 protected void setUpHeader(int headerRequestingActivity) {
    setContentView(headerRequestingActivity);
    headerPresenter = new HeaderPresenterImpl(this);
    drawerHeaderView = findViewById(R.id.navigationheader);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tbHeader);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    final NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                //do something on opening the navigation
            } else {
                //optional actions when navigation menu closes
            }
        }
    };
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
}
```

And listening for clicks with following method:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.nav_changelanguage:
            //change language logic
            break;
        case R.id.nav_logout:
            //logout user
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i'm posting my main.xml file above because i think my setup is a bit strange. i only included my nav_header inside the NavigationView widget and then assigned the menu using app:menu ... but how could this cause the problem? I've seen in numerous posts that what you just said was the actual problem but i don't see any other views on top of the navView one. Maybe you can see something i don't :(

Comment: I added a full example of how I integrate my header across different activities. Also, I didn't see you close your drawerLayout in your layout xml.

Comment: yeah i forgot to TAB the last line :P . I'm going to try and implement some of your code into mine and see if i can figure something out here. Thank you for trying to help me

Comment: sadly this listeningforclicks method is not working for me. It baffles me that i can't seem to spot the root of this issue. Could it be the ToggleButton ? Maybe somehow it overlaps the navView ?

Comment: figured it out....hadn't realized that i should use onNavigationItemSelected instead of onOptionsItemSelected :D